# Google Line Chart customize x axis week number to month

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have some data that summarizes unit count by week by year.  IOW's, my datatable looks like this:

> Week/  2012/   2013/   2014/   2015
>
> 1/ 45/ 45/ 31/ 28
>
> 2/ 45/ 52/ 54/ 58
>
> 3/ 40/ 42/ 62/ 51
>
> 4/ 41/ 50/ 58/ 50
>
> 5/ 43/ 46/ 58/ 46
>
> 6/ 41/ 49/ 56/ 56

...and so on (sorry about the formatting).  I am displaying this data in a Google Line Chart - multiple lines, one line for each year.  My challenge is: how to display (alpha) months on the x-axis of the line chart? (Currently I get week numbers, which don't mean much to anyone!)

SEE COMMENTS BELOW FOR ANSWER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your starting point is a dataset with "by week" data you wont be able to use it for displaying monthly data. Not accurately anyway.

What you really want to do is to change your query so as to get a dataset with monthly data.

Comment: I understand your suggestion (thank you), but we really want to display the data movement by week - essentially, I'd like to display the months so that the viewer can identify the month that belongs to the week#.  A background image would work nicely, but I don't see that option.

Comment: Ok, stated like that it makes much more sense. Check the api documentation here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference , you have several things to explore. I'd say the ChartWrapper Class and maybe the Data Manipulation Methods are worth looking into.

Comment: Also check the **hAxis.ticks** options for overriding the x axis display. See the configuration options here  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options

Comment: **hAxis.ticks** - that's exactly what I wanted.  I was trying to make it way too difficult.  Thank you very much!  I want to show the question answered, but your original answer really didn't answer the question - how do I give you credit for answering the question?